# Angular 2: Event Emitter not working properly

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have two components. I have a help menu component and a navigation component. When a user clicks the help button, it should show the help menu. I made a variable called help in the app component. In the nav component, I made an event emitter to try two-way binding, but it doesn't work on the nav component. I am kinda confused because the variable help only works when the app loads, but not when I click the help button.

**app component.ts**

```
help:boolean = true;
```

**App component html**

```
<!-- app menu div -->
<app-help [(helps)]="help"></app-help>

<!-- app navigation -->
<app-nav [help]="help"></app-nav>
```

**App-nav component html**

```
<button class="circle" (click)="helpMenu()">H</button>
```

**App-nav component.ts**

```
export class NavComponent implements OnInit{

@Input() help:boolean;
@Output() HelpsChange: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

constructor(){}

// when user clicks the help button
helpMenu(){
    this.help = true;
    this.HelpsChange.emit(this.help);
 }
}
```

**App-help component.html**

```
<div id="helpMenu" *ngIf="help==true">
<p>Help</p>
<button (click)="closeHelp()">Close</button>
```

**App-help component.ts**

```
export class HelpComponent implements OnInit {

@Input()  help:boolean;
@Output() helpsChange: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {
}

closeHelp(){
 this.help = false; 
 this.helpsChange.emit(this.help);
}

}
```

Comment: You have typo, `<app-help [(helps)]="help"></app-help>` should be `<app-help [(help)]="help"></app-help>` you don't have any variable named `helps`

Comment: @FabioAntunes Good catch. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Not just changing the `[(helps)]` to `[(help)]` like Fabio mentioned, but you also need to change the name of the variable in the directive to remove the `s` from `helpsChange`. It's important that the input and output follow the naming format `property/propertyChange`, when you when you want to use the "banana in a box" syntax `[()]`

Comment: So I made sure all the properties matched, it only updates the variable from app-nav.

Comment: Banana in a box syntax lol. Never heard this before now